# C++ lambda expression for method chains

Tags: c++, lambda

Let's say I have a `Car` object which also has an `Engine` member, and I want to inspect the properties of the object, calling some methods on `Car` and some methods in `Engine`. To get te info explicitly I could do

```
cout << "my car has " << mycar.GetEngine().NCylinders() << " cylinders" << endl;
cout << "my car has " << mycar.NWheels() << " wheels" << endl;
```

all these calls are of the form `mycar.<some method call chain here>`. (you can also assume that they all have a compatible return types). How can I have a list of functors, so that I can pass an `Car` instance and it will execute the calls accordingly.?

I have come up with a solution using `<tr1/functional>` using nested  binds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

struct Engine{
    int NCylinders() const {return 12;}
};

struct Car{
    int    NWheels() const {return 4;}
    Engine GetEngine() const {return myEngine;}
private:
    Engine myEngine;
};

int main(){   
    Car mycar;

    map<string,function<double (const Car&)> > carinfos;
    carinfos["cylinders"]   = bind(&Engine::NCylinders,bind(&Car::GetEngine,_1));
    carinfos["wheels"]      = bind(&Car::NWheels,_1);

    map<string,function<double (const Car&)> >::const_iterator info = carinfos.begin();
    for(;info!=carinfos.end();++info){
        cout << "my car has: " << (info->second)(mycar) << " " << info->first << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs nicely:

```
my car has: 12 cylinders
my car has: 4 wheels
```

But the nested binds can get ugly with longer chains or methods in the middle that have to have fixed arguments and I was wondering if there may be a solution using lambda expressions which could result in something like

```
 //pseudocode
 carinfos["cylinders"]   = (_1.GetEngine().NCylinder());
 carinfos["wheels"]   = (_1.GetNWheel());
```

Edit:

@KennyTM and @Kerrek SB have provided excellent answers using the new C++11 lambda expressions. I cannot yet use C++11, so I would appreciate solutions of similar conciseness using C++03

Comment: Maybe a visitor pattern? "Wheel visitor, Cylinder visitor"... the implementation function of the visitor could be a lambda.

Comment: Yes that would work, but I cannot change the interfaces of the classes.

Comment: In your pseudocode, the last line should have "nwheel", not "cylinders", right?

Comment: If you can use C++11, then you could use true lambdas. `[](const Car& car){ return car.GetEngine().NCylinder(); };`. BTW, are you sure you want to pass `car` by value?

Comment: since you are saying lambda, I think you want to use c++11 and if yes, then Kenny TM's comment would work.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes it should not be passed by value, obviously. The C++11 example is exactly what I am looking for, but was hoping it can be achieved using some tr1/boost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following, using lambdas rather than binds, doesn't look too awful:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::function<int(Car const &)>> visitor;

int main()
{
  visitor v;
  v["wheels"]    = [](Car const & c) -> int { return c.NWheels(); };
  v["cylinders"] = [](Car const & c) -> int { return c.GetEngine().NCylinders(); };

  Car c;

  for (auto it = v.cbegin(), end = v.cend(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    std::cout << "My car has " << it->second(c) << " " << it->first << ".\n";
  }
}
```

The loop could be wrapped up in a `visit(c, v);` function.

Comment: I guess this is the canonical answer for C++11.

Comment: +1 Small side note, in this particular lambda, that contains a single `return` expression and no other code, the return type is optional, so it could be spelled as: `[]( Car const & c ) { return c.NWheels(); }`